# How to correctly catch exceptions while view is loading

Tags: ios, exception, try-catch

I want to understand how can I correctly catch and show to user reason of exception, which have been appeared while processing viewDidLoad? I've tried to solve this problem like this, but I faced the problem with showing AlertWindow.
Error: unrecognized selector sent to instance and terminating app due to uncaught exception.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    @try {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        APPDataBase *sharedDataBase = [APPDataBase sharedDataBase];
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        recievedArray = [recievedURL componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        [self fillUpTableViewWithTitles];
        if ([self isInternetConnected]){
            [sharedDataBase saveData:feeds WithKey:@"savedFeeds"];
        }
        else
        {
            feeds = [sharedDataBase loadDataWithKey:@"savedFeeds"];
        }
        [NSException raise:@"Invalid smth" format:@"Error error error, dangerous, wow"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        [self showAlertWindowWithString:exception];
    }
}
```

And showAlertWindowWithString: method code

```
-(void)showAlertWindowWithString:(NSString *)string{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:string message:@"Press OK button." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    alertController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        [self okButtonTapped];
    }]];

    UIViewController *topRootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    while (topRootViewController.presentedViewController){
        topRootViewController = topRootViewController.presentedViewController;
    }

    [topRootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I'm messed up a bit, because I have access only to iDevice Emulator, so I want to catch "real-life device" errors at least using this way. Or, maybe, there're any other ways to make the App not crash while this type of exception happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an `NSException *` to your `showAlertWindowWithString:` method but receiving it as an `NSString *`, but `string` is still an `NSException` - you then pass this to `alertControllerWithTitle` - As soon as that method tries to perform an `NSString` operation on the `NSException` you are going to get an unrecognized selector exception.

You could do something like:

```
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    [self showAlertWindowWithString:exception.reason];
}
```

But really, `@try/@catch` isn't a common paradigm in Objective C iOS programming.  It is more common to simply check for errors and take appropriate actions or display user friendly alerts & messages.  Exceptions should be generally identified during development and you fix the underlying cause of the exception.

Comment: Thank you for help, I'll try check all the possible problem fragments in code and "take appropriate actions or display user friendly alerts & messages" ´=)